# Refresh X11 display on an unfocussed virtual console

Tags: linux, x11, virtual-consoles

I am running two X11 desktop sessions (via 2x `startx`) on two different virtual consoles.

I am using a chromecast to continuously cast X11 running on the second virtual console, **vt7**, as a kind of external display (rather than only being able to mirror one display).

Currently, if I am on vt1, the image cast from vt7 is frozen. When I switch back to vt7, the image on my screen quickly flashes to the updated image and the casted image updates accordingly.

Is there a way to force a refresh or re-render of vt7 without switching to it? Or even a way to briefly switch to it and then switch back automatically?

I have tried `xrefresh -display ":1"` without success.